# cannot find min-height in wordpress css style sheet, how can i override it

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, google-chrome-devtools

Im having problems finding min-height in my css style sheet.
In chrome developer, in element.style is that option, that when i uncheck it, the feature image goes in auto resize, and when min-height is checked, the feature image, it goes zoomed.
Can someone help me where to find it or how can i override, or how to find the class of min.height and override it.

**Template code**

```html
?>
<div class="project-detail-splitted">   
    <?php if (!empty($prague_post_options['active_title'])): ?>
    <section class="container-fluid top-banner no-padd simple fullheight light">
        <span class="overlay"></span>
        <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array('class'=>'s-img-switch') ); ?> 
        <div class="content">
            <?php if (!empty($prague_post_options['subtitle'])): ?>
                <div class="subtitle">
                    <?php echo esc_html( $prague_post_options['subtitle'] ); ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif ?> 
            <?php the_title( '<h1 class="title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
        </div>
    </section>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

**here is a picture of how its looks like**
[image: 1.Zoomed Feature Image]

**When min.height is not checked, or not used.**
[image: 2. Normal Picture without min.height]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to look in the template settings. The code is added by javascript.

See you have a 'full-height' class. I would see if it can be changed in the template settings.

Your template is called 'Prague' which I can see has documentation - maybe it's worth reading.

Fast solution by css - not recommended:

```
.top-banner.fullheight {
min-height: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: i inserted code template, maybe this is the problem full? <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full'